# Write formatted xml with Xml Bean

Tags: java, xmlbeans

I have created a xml with Xml bean and now it's time to write the created xml in a file. But when I am writing my file in the xml file it's unformatted. So, I need to help to write the formatted xml into the file. My Code is given below:

**document contains the xml and it's a object of org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject**

```
File file = new File("test.xml");
document.save(file);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlBeans.save()` uses `toString()` to get the XML string, which is not formatted. Due to this the string in your file is unformatted as well. For formatted output do the following:

```
XmlOptions xmlOptions = new XmlOptions();
xmlOptions.setSavePrettyPrint();
document.save(file, xmlOptions);
```